# JQuery Version and Editing Tool Tips

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using a tooltip edit script that includes the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>

<script>
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[title]").style_my_tooltips({
                tip_follows_cursor: true,
                tip_delay_time: 90,
                tip_fade_speed: 600,
                attribute: "title"
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

But, due to another script I am using, I need to use this version of jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Trying to use the 2.1.4 breaks the tooltips style. Help? I am super super new to jQuery and Javascript.

Comment: You can use two jquery version. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: So, I don't know enough javascript or jQuery to understand anything that's going on with that link...Like I said I'm super new.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ali said in his comment, you can use jQuery's noConflict function.

By default, jQuery uses `$` as a shorthand function name. Using `jQuery.noConflict()` you can bind this to something else.

This means, as shown in the linked answer, you can do the following:

For version 1.7, you can do the following:
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var jQ = $.noConflict(true);
</script>`

Now, instead of `$(document).ready()` you can use `jQ(document).ready()` to access jQuery 1.7 functions.

jQuery 2.1.4 will still be accessible through `$`.

Do note that jQuery 1.7 is 6 years old, and might be obsolete. Consider looking for a more up-to-date version of the Tooltip library you're using.

[Bootstrap has the functionality you're looking for!](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tooltip.asp)